# Adjusting labels for a pandas bar graph;

Tags: python, pandas, graph, charts, label

Out of curiosity, how do you adjust graph labels from PD labels?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMXPs.png)

```
#Create bar charts to show outliers:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a1['Word #'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', x='Word #', y='Frequency')
```

I tried to label it differently but I don't think it's working right. I appreciate all your help!

Comment: You could make a bigger figure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `xlabel()` and `ylabel()`?

```
#Create bar charts to show outliers:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
a1['Word #'].value_counts().plot(ax=ax, kind='bar', x='Word #', y='Frequency')

plt.xlabel("Label what you want")
plt.ylabel("Label what you want")
plt.show()
```

or

```
ax.set_xlabel('xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel('ylabel')
plt.show()
```

This can also be better for your example:

```
lt.xticks(rotation=90)
```